# Android - How to detect same user from multiple devices?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing an app that sends user-created data to a server.

Is it possible to recognise the same user when he is using the app on different devices **without** my app having to request access to his Google account, requiring additional permissions or asking him to create custom login credentials? (This is important as my app needs to work for 'anonymous' users.)

My app uses push notifications and, for any given user, I understand that the token ID generated by FireBase may be the same for each of his device installations of the app. So I am considering using these token IDs to identify the same user across multiple devices. However, I'm not sure how reliable that approach would be - or if there is a better way?

NB - I found [Best Practices for Unique Identifiers](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids.html#e_handle_multiple_installations) (the [Handling Multiple Installations](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids.html) section in particular), but it hasn't helped.

Comment: A Firebase Cloud Messaging Instance ID token does exactly what its name implies: it identifies an instance of the app, so the installation of the specific app on a specific device/profile. It does not in any way identify a user. If you want to identify the user, you'll have to somehow authenticate them, e.g. with Firebase Authentication or use their existing, active profile in Android.

Answer (score 1):

We can manage multiple installation with same account,

1. Generate device token using firebase
2. store token locally and on server also
3. on splash screen always check token stored locally with token stored on serever
4. if it shows differences ask user to keep only one device active to receive notification ,
   if user selected current device store that token to server.